# How to generate a typelib for gir file with waf

Tags: introspection, vala, typelib, waf

I use the following wscript_build snippet to build a vala library with its gir file:

```
lib = bld.shlib (
  features = 'c cshlib',
  target = 'sample',
  name = 'libsample',
  vnum = '0.0.0',
  vapi_dirs = '../vapi',
  uselib = 'GTK',
  cflags = ['-include', 'config.h'],
  gir = 'Sample-1.0',
  packages = 'gtk+-3.0',
  packages_private = 'config',
  source = bld.path.ant_glob (incl='**/*.vala'))
```

However now I'm wondering how to build a typelib from this gir file with waf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool g-ir-compiler available in the debian package gobject-introspection converts a gir file to a typelib (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030566/how-to-generate-gir-files-from-the-vala-compiler))

Following task definition can be used within wscript_build to use this tool to build a typelib within waf and install such to /usr/lib/girepository-1.0 where it belongs.

```
lib_typelib = bld.new_task_gen(
  name = 'libsample_typelib',
  after = 'libsample',
  source = 'Sample-1.0.gir',
  target = 'Sample-1.0.typelib',
  install_path = '${LIBDIR}/girepository-1.0',
  rule='g-ir-compiler ${SRC} -o ${TGT}')
```

For a complete sample also see [here](http://gitorious.org/gjs-clutter-sample/mainline/blobs/master/wscript)